# Store multiple items in IPC::ShareLite object

Tags: perl, fork, ipc

I have a Perl program that forks subprocesses and processes N items in them, after that I need to return these processed items to main process.

From multiple available IPC options to return processed items to main process, [IPC::ShareLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::ShareLite) seems to be a simplest one, but I'm not sure if it supports storing multiple items in one shared object.

Here is a snippet from the program, but it doesn't work:

```perl
use IPC::ShareLite;

# create shared object in main process
my $share = new IPC::ShareLite(
    -key     => 1234,
    -create  => 'yes',
    -destroy => 'yes'
) or die $!;

# fork subprocesses, process and store N items in shared object
$share->store($member);

# After subprocesses finish, fetch items in main process
my $members_size = scalar @$members_ref;
@$members_ref = ();
while ($members_size > 0) {
    my $member = $share->fetch();
    push @$members_ref, $member;
    $members_size--;
}
```

Above code fails with quite obscure error on `my $member = $share->fetch();`:

> IPC::ShareLite fetch() error: Invalid argument at ...

Is it possible to use IPC::ShareLite object as I intend or it can hold only one item?

Comment: That code you posted doesn't run, much less demonstrate the problem. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a child using `fork`, and this child gets a copy of the `$share` object. When the child exits, the child's copy of the `$share` object is destroyed, which causes the underlying system resources to be destroyed because you used `-destroy => 'yes'`.

In general, you want to create objects with destructors *after* performing the forks.

But when creating a IPC::ShareLite object, you normally want to leave key to let the system choose the key for you, but you need to do that before creating the forks.

**Workaround**

Perform the following in the child:

```
$share->destroy(0);
```

**A better solution**

Since the a normal usage mode for the module involves creating an object inherited by child processes, the module should handle that situation.

To that end, you should have the module's maintainer change the module so that the destruction only occurs if the current PID is the same as the PID in which `$share` was created.

```
sub _initialize {
  ...
  $self->{pid} = $$;   # ADD
  ...
}

sub DESTROY {
  my $self = shift;

  #destroy_share( $self->{share}, $self->{destroy} )                           # REMOVE
  destroy_share( $self->{share}, $self->{pid} == $$ ? $self->{destroy} : 0 )   # ADD
   if $self->{share};
}
```